# Проблема с потоками в Spring-mvc приложении

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring-mvc

Есть проект на Spring-MVC. В проекте есть класс `JRecorder extends Thread`, с методами `start()` и `stop()` и Контроллер, в котором объявлены `@RequestMapping(value = "/start")` и `@RequestMapping(value = "/stop")`, нужно чтобы в `/start` выполнялся метод `start()` класса `JRecorder`, а в `/stop` - соответственно метод `stop()`. 
Я пытался сделать след. образом:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
...
JRecorder rec = new JRecorder(param1, param2, param3);
...

@RequestMapping(value = "/start")
....
rec.start();
...

@RequestMapping(value = "/stop")
...
rec.stop();
```

При такой реализации после остановки записи через localhost/stop, следующий старт записи выкидывает ошибку: HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException.

Подскажите как правильно реализовать обращение к методам и вообще в какую сторону копать?

Полный листинг класса JRecorder:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat.Type;

public class JRecorder extends Thread    {

private TargetDataLine        m_line;
private AudioFileFormat.Type    m_targetType;
private AudioInputStream    m_audioInputStream;
private File            m_outputFile;


public JRecorder(){

}

public void setM_line(TargetDataLine m_line) {
    this.m_line = m_line;
    this.m_audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(m_line);
}

public void setM_targetType(Type m_targetType) {
    this.m_targetType = m_targetType;
}

public void setM_outputFile(File m_outputFile) {
    this.m_outputFile = m_outputFile;
}

public void start()
{
    m_line.start();

       super.start();
     }

public void stopRecording()
{
    m_line.stop();
    m_line.close();
}


public void run()
{
    try
    {
        AudioSystem.write(
                m_audioInputStream,
                m_targetType,
                m_outputFile);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Полный листинг класса MainController:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
@Autowired
private JRecorder jRecorder; //= new JRecorder();

public JRecorder getjRecorder(){
    return jRecorder;
}

public void setjRecorder(JRecorder jRecorder){
    this.jRecorder = jRecorder;
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView main() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("index");
    return modelAndView;
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/start")
public ModelAndView start() {
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    ReadFromFile rff = new ReadFromFile();
    DateAndTime dat = new DateAndTime();

    String path = rff.getPath();
    String name = rff.getName();
    String date = dat.getDate();
    String time = dat.getTime();

    File outputFile = new File(path+name+"-"+date+"-"+time+".wav");

    AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(
            16000, 8, 1, false, false);

    DataLine.Info    info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);
    TargetDataLine    targetDataLine = null;

    {
        try {
            targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    AudioFileFormat.Type    targetType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;

    modelAndView.setViewName("start");

    jRecorder = this.getjRecorder();
    jRecorder.setM_line(targetDataLine);
    jRecorder.setM_targetType(targetType);
    jRecorder.setM_outputFile(outputFile);
    jRecorder.start();

    System.out.println("Start rec");
    return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/stop")
public ModelAndView stop() {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    modelAndView.setViewName("stop");
    jRecorder = this.getjRecorder();
    jRecorder.stopRecording();
    System.out.println("Stop rec");
    return modelAndView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не наследуйте `JRecorder` от `Thread`. Замените наследование композицией.

Пусть `JRecorder` при вызове `start()` создает новый поток (если он еще не создан), кладет его в `volatile` поле и запускает.

В методе `stopRecording()` стопайте поток и очищайте поле.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя делать Thread.start() после того как поток уже раз отработал, собственно, о чем и говорит IllegalThreadStateException. Нужно создать новый экземпляр JRecorder и стартовать его.

Comment: Понятно, у меня как раз в этом и проблема, я не могу понять как и где правильно инициализировать экземпляр класса, чтобы он был доступен в обоих маппингах.